# The ViewData item that has the key 'HousingId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application I'm working on. I have an Application Create View that works just fine. But I wanted to create a partial view so I could call it in the Index. However that partial view throws

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ViewData item that has the key 'HousingId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'

on this line of code:

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("HousingId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Housings, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Yet that line of code works fine in the normal Create view. Here is my controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var housings = new SelectList(_db.Housings.ToList(), "HousingId", "Name");
    ViewBag.Housings = housings;
    return View();
}
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Here is how I'm passing the partial

```html
@model IEnumerable<Housing_RedBadgeMVC.Models.ApplicationModels.ApplicationListItem>

...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="create-housing-container">
        <p style="color: white; font-size: 12px;">
            Here you can view current applications for specific housing,
            if you'd like to fill out an application please click
            @Html.Partial("_ApplicationCreate", item)
        </p>
    </div>
}

...
```

And what's in the partial:

```html
@model Housing_RedBadgeMVC.Models.ApplicationModels.ApplicationListItem

...

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Application", new { id = Model.HousingId }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HousingId, "Housing", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("HousingId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Housings, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HousingId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}

...
```

Comment: You are not showing how you call your partial view and what's in it.

Comment: I call it from index by @Html.Partial("_ApplicationCreate", item) and as what's inside it is the same as my ApplicationCreate but in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: MVC is not concerned with bootstrap modals. Please edit your question to show the code around the call to Html.Partial, and the code in the partial. You are passing a model to the partial, are you even using the model from the partial?

Comment: You can't be calling that view from the `ActionResult Create()` that you've shown. The parent view expects a model, you are not passing one. Apparently you have another controller method that actually calls this view, and it sets an integer for `ViewBag.Housings`. I've also taken the liberty to edit your code to only show the relevant parts.

Comment: I'm not calling the view from ActionResult Create(), it's called from ActionResult Index() but if I understand correctly I still can't pass that view?

Comment: If it's called from `ActionResult Index()` then please show that.

Comment: That is the Index View where I have "Here is where I'm calling my partial view. It's called from the view, not the controller sorry If I didn't clarify.

Comment: I understand that. Please show you are calling that Index view.

Answer (score -1):

It says that the Dropdownlist must be List where as you are just passing single object like `var`

Change this:

```
var housings = new SelectList(_db.Housings.ToList(), "HousingId", "Name");
```

to

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> housings = new SelectList(_db.Housings.ToList(), "HousingId", "Name");
```

**EDIT**:

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> housings = db.Housings.Select(
    b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.HousingId, Text = b.Name}).ToString();
ViewBag.Housings = housings;
```

Comment: b.HousingId is "cannot convert int to string". I do have HousingId set as a [Key] of int in my data.

Comment: Add .ToString() in the end. Check the way I have written.

Comment: My bad I didn't see that, same result though.